# Rendering ASPX Page without a request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASPX page that I intend to use as a template to generate some HTML. I have defined my markup and data bound controls and built a function to do all the data binding, call this.Render and return the HTML. The function works just fine when called from Page_Load.

My intent was to bypass page request and directly call the method and get the page HTML, but when I call the function without making a HTTP Request, none of my server side controls are initialized.

Is there any way I can call a method on a page, pass some params and get the HTML output without making a HTTP Request. I believe Server.Execute could do it but i cant find a way to pass params in it.

I am calling the function like this

```
MyPage ThreadHTMLGenerator = new MyPage;
string threadHTML= ThreadHTMLGenerator.GenerateExpandedHTML(param1, param2, param3);
```

Comment: How are you currently calling the method if not by HTTP request?

Comment: Sometime ago i needed to do the very same thing, and [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/481.aspx) helped me a lot. It covers exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use [Server.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb04e8f7.aspx):

```
var page = new MyPage();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
```

Alternatively if you need to pass your own querystring parameters, you could do a WebRequest to yourself:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.mysite.com/page.aspx?param1=1&param2=2");
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();
var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
var reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();
```

Comment: This doesnt help. Look at the edited question. Where do param1,param2 go in this case

Comment: Some caveats of hitting your own server from a page to be aware of: 1) ASP.NET session state only allows one request per session, so you might go into a deadlock. Solution: check out `IReadOnlySessionState`.  2) If your site is behind a load balancer that has cookies/session state only on one machine and no shared state then you have to make sure to hit the same machine in the request.